# [Python][Adobe Acrobat] Save PDF as Excel problem

Tags: python, acrobat

I am working on converting PDF to Excel by adobe acrobat Pro and Python. Recently, the program can open adobe acrobat but it can save the pdf as excel file. Acrobat pop up an error message

> ***The specified file could not be written to. It may be in use.***

I have no idea what is problem.

```py
import win32com.client, win32com.client.makepy, os, winerror, pandas as pd, errno, re
from win32com.client.dynamic import ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT

class Acrobat_scan_automation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.directory_path = r'D:\Desktop\Desktop_2\1.Python_project\ACROBAT_SCAN_AUTOMATION'
        os.chdir(self.directory_path)
        self.folder_name = {
            "output": r'output',
            "source": r'source',
            }
        self.excel_file = r'output.xlsx'
        self.output_csv = r'output_1.csv'
        self.pdf_file = r'arabic.pdf'
        return

    def pdf2excel(self,pdf_file,excel_file):
        try:
            ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)
            src = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.folder_name['source'],pdf_file))
            print('[INFO] abspath=',src)
            win32com.client.makepy.GenerateFromTypeLibSpec('Acrobat')
            adobe = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.App')
            avDoc = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.AVDoc')
            print('[INFO] Open',src)
            avDoc.Open(src, src)
            pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
            print('[INFO] pdDoc=',pdDoc)
            jsObject = pdDoc.GetJSObject()
            print('[INFO] jObject=',jsObject)
            export_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.folder_name['output'],excel_file))
            jsObject.SaveAs(export_file, 'com.adobe.acrobat.xlsx')   # < ---- Error

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

        finally:        
            # avDoc.Close(True)
            jsObject = None
            pdDoc = None
            avDoc = None
            return

    def main(self):
        print('[INFO] Start using acrobat')
        self.pdf2excel(self.pdf_file, self.excel_file)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Program = Acrobat_scan_automation()
    Program.main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-install adobe acrobat to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I did face this error. Reinstalling didn't work for me. 
The following solution worked:

1. Open Adobe Acrobat Pro.
2. Navigate to Edit-> Preferences-> Security (Enhanced) and uncheck the "Enable Protected Mode at startup" under Sandbox Protections.
3. Scroll down click Ok.
4. Restart your system. 

   Reference:
   [image: uncheck Sandbox preferences]